# How to suppress pageheader when printrecord finished?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I am facing problem in crystal report with page header.page header should display only have records.if record ends Header should not display.For that i tried 'onrecordlast' in page header suppress formula.Its working if more records not only one record. Help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

http://scn.sap.com/thread/1651675 please refer this website.its working now.